# Objective-C static, extern, public variables

Tags: objective-c, static, public, extern

I want to have a variable that I can access anywhere by importing a header file but I also want it to be static in the sense that there is only one of them created.  In my .m file, I specify

```
static BOOL LogStuff = NO;
```

and in the initialize method I set the logging value:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    LogStuff = ... //whatever
}
```

However I want to be able to access my variable anywhere by importing the .h file so I want to do something like this:

```
static extern BOOL LogStuff;
```

but I'm not allowed to do that.  Is it possible to do the thing I'm trying to do?  Thanks

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`static` in Objective-C means a different thing than `static` in a C++ class, in the context of static class data members and static class methods.  In C and Objective-C, a `static` variable or function at global scope means that that symbol has *internal linkage*.

Internal linkage means that that symbol is local to the current *translation unit*, which is the current source file (`.c` or `.m`) being compiled and all of the header files that it recursively includes.  That symbol cannot be referenced from a different translation unit, and you can have other symbols with internal linkage in other translation units with the same name.

So, if you have a header file declaring a variable as `static`, each source file that includes that header gets a *separate* global variable—all references to that variable within one source file will refer to the same variable, but references in different source files will refer to *different* variables.

If you want to have a single global variable, you can't have it in class scope like in C++.  One option is to create a global variable with *external linkage*: declare the variable with the `extern` keyword in a header file, and then in **one** source file, define it at global scope without the `extern` keyword.  Internal linkage and external linkage are mutually exclusive—you cannot have a variable declared as both `extern` and `static`.

An alternative, as [Panos suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642304/objective-c-static-extern-public-variables/7642360#7642360), would be to use a class method instead of a variable.  This keeps the functionality within the scope of the class, which makes more sense semantically, and you can also make it `@private` if you so desire.  It does add a marginal performance penalty, but that's highly unlikely to be the bottleneck in your application (if you suspect it is, always profile first).

Comment: "then in one source file, define it at global scope without the extern keyword" => What happens if I don't? I am surprised that there is no compiler error out of this.

Comment: @huggie: You'll *likely* get a linker error like "symbol(s) not found" or "duplicate symbol".

Comment: +1 for " Internal linkage and external linkage are mutually exclusive"

Comment: "all references to that variable within one source file will refer to the same variable, but references in different source files will refer to different variables." I created a project to try and recreate this, but I'm having trouble. I created a header (StaticHeader01.h) that declares a static variable, and two other files (Test01.h|m Test02.h|m) that import StaticHeader01.h and printed out the memory address of the static variable. However, the memory addresses are the same. Can you point out what I'm missing?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield:  Is there any difference in declaring a global const NSString with and without static keyword? If it is global, does keyword static add any value?

static NSString *const kSiteURL           = @“https://www.google.com”; vs 

NSString *const kSiteURL           = @“https://www.google.com”;

Answer (score 6):

If `LogStuff` is a static class field, maybe you can implement static getter and setter?

```
+ (void)setLogStuff:(BOOL)aLogStuff;
+ (BOOL)logStuff;
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare it `extern BOOL` in your header file.  Files that `#import` your header don't know or care if the external symbol is static or not.

Answer (score 3):

Separate global variable (one per source file):

```
// .h
static NSString * aStatic;

//.m
static NSString * aStatic = @"separate";
```

Unique global variable:

```
// .h
extern NSString * anExtern;

// .m
NSString * anExtern = @"global";
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this layout for my statics:

```
NSMutableArray *macroArray;
BOOL keepMacro;

+ (void) startMacro
{
    if (macroArray == nil)
    {
        macroArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    }

    [macroArray removeAllObjects];
    keepMacro = YES;
}
```

This is the `startMacro` command in my application. Both the `Bool` and the `macroArray` are static, but notice they are not declared `static` or `extern`.

This may not be the best practice, but this is what I do.